# is nicotine considered an intoxicant within islam?

Tags: halal-haram

i have been doing lots of research on this topic and can’t find a clear answer anywhere, can someone please help me with this topic on wether nicotine is an intoxicant or not. i have come to the conclusion that it is haram because harming yourself is haram, but is it classed a an intoxicant aswell? i have been researching this topic for days but cannot find a clear answer anywhere. can someone please clear this up for me?

Comment: There is difference of opinion on that. See [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11430/5876#p6) and [here](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11430/5882#p6).

Answer (score 1):

Nicotine is a dangerous and highly addictive chemical. It can cause an increase in blood pressure, heart rate, flow of blood to the heart and a narrowing of the arteries (vessels that carry blood). Nicotine may also contribute to the hardening of the arterial walls, which in turn, may lead to a heart attack. So yes it is haram and it’s best to not do it. Allah knows best